# calculate polynom value assembly 32 bit

Tags: assembly, masm, 32-bit

I need to calculate a polynomial at a certain point using the coprocessor, but I have few problems with the implementation. My program doesn't show anything and registers behave very strangely when I load power on stack, i use MASM 32 bit assembly

Example : For P(X) = 1.2 + 3X + 4.9X^3 + 8.27X^4 i will have the variables:
 p DD 1.2, 3, 0, 4.9, 8.27 ,n EQU ($-p)/4 -1 and the output will be the polynom in a certain point

My code:

```
    .386

    .model flat, stdcall
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    ;include libraries
    includelib msvcrt.lib
    extern exit: proc
    extern printf: proc
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


    public start
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    .data

    ;p is my array of coefficients
    p DD 1.2, 3, 0, 4.9, 8.27
    n equ ($-p)/type p

    ;x is the value in which I calculate the polynomial
    x dq 3.0
    zero dq 0.0
    doi dq 2.0
    power dd 0
    valoare dd 0
    format DB "%lf", 0
    .code
    start:
        ;move in ecx the numbers of coefficients
        mov ecx,n

        ;edx is the index for my array
        xor edx,edx

        ;ebx is my array
        mov ebx,offset p

        FINIT ;INITIALIZARE COPROCESOR

        fld zero
        polinom:
        ;calculate x to power
        fld power
        FLD x   ;st[0]=x, st[1]=power
        FYL2X ; st[1]=st[1]*log2(st[0])
        FLD1 ; st[0]=1, st[1] = FYL2X 
        FXCH st(1)
        FSUB  ST(0), ST(1); st[0]=st[0]-st[1]
        F2XM1 
        FLD1
        FADD ST(0), ST(1)
        FLD doi
        FMUL

        ;multiply it by the corresponding coefficient
        FLD QWORD ptr [ebx+edx]
        FMUL
        add eax,4
        inc power
        ;the value coeff* x ^ y will be in st (0) and the partial value of the polynomial will be in st(5)
        ;example for 3x^2+2x+1, in st(0) will be 3x^2 and in st(5) will be 2x+1

        FXCH ST(1)
        FXCH ST(5)
        FADD
        loop polinom

        ;FST ST[0]  ;SAVE RESULT
        lea edi,valoare
        FST QWORD ptr[edi]

        ;SHOW RESULT
        push dword ptr [valoare+4]
        push dword ptr [valoare]
        push offset format
        call printf
        add esp, 12


        ;terminarea programului
        push 0
        call exit
    end start
```

Comment: You don't need `FYL2X` for integer powers.  Get `x^3` from `x^2 * x`, and so on, in a loop, multiply by the coefficient, and add to the total.

Comment: yes, i know it will be more easier that, but my teacher ask me to use fyl2x and f2xm1 to calculate x^y

Comment: i couldn't find anything about overflow on coprocessor and because of this i've done things like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define your array of coefficients as dwords, i.e. 32-bit `float`.

`p DD 1.2, 3, 0, 4.9, 8.27`

But then you use `FLD QWORD ptr [ebx+edx]` to load a qword (64-bit `double`) from it.  So you're treating the bit-patterns of two adjacent `float`s as one `double`.

Also, you're loading the same `double` every time because you never modify `ebx` or `edx` after setting `ebx=p` and `edx=0`.

**Use `fmul dword ptr [ebx]` / `add ebx, 4`**

---

**You're also going to overflow the x87 register stack so `fld` produces NaN**, when `st(0)` .. `st(7)` are already in use.  You don't seem to be popping anything ever. See http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/index.html, and other links in  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

Use `fmulp`, `faddp`, and `fstp` to pop values when you're done with them. 
 Or `fmul` with a memory operand instead of `fld` + `fmulp`.

I have no idea what other bugs your code might have, but you definitely have these bugs and those both explain seeing major weirdness in FP registers while debugging.

---

BTW, you can use `sub esp,8` / `fstp qword ptr [esp]` to store the result directly onto the call stack as an arg for `printf`.  You don't need `valoare`.

---

Or better, use SSE2 `mulsd` for scalar FP math, instead of x87, but apparently your assignment requires you to use x87 `fyl2x` to do this in a very inefficient way, and apparently with x87.

If you weren't forced to do it the inefficient way, you could just do `power *= x` to get x, x^2, x^3, ... in a loop.  Building up a power one multiply at a time instead of redoing the each power separate is called a strength-reduction optimization, like turning `tmp = i*10` into `tmp += 10`.